# Design pattern for data lookups in JSON objects

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

So writing an application which uses a lot of user generated data. And in most cases I just use the mongodb id to look up whatever it is. So a typical example for this app is icons for categories. They are stored as a data set that gets passed around the application from the api that speaks to the mongodb to the api to a factory and then to the controller, and quite often I need to make a simple lookup. Lets say that the category looks as follows:

```
[
   {
       "_id":"55dc79efed0fcf4a58d4a68d",
       "categoryName":"Sport",
       "categoryDescription":"Sport and more sports",
       "categoryIcon":"55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a68c",
       "__v":0
   }
]
```

categoryIcon is a reference to another table, at the time loaded in a factory, data looks as follows.

```
[
   {
       "_id":"55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a68c",
       "iconName":"Sport",
       "cssString":"fa fa-futbol-o",
        "__v":0
    },
    {
       "_id":"55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a69d",
       "iconName":"Travel",
       "cssString":
       "fa fa-plane",
       "__v":0
    }
]
```

So the way I have been resolving this is along the lines of

```
for (var i in icons){
    if( icons[i]._id == category.categoryIcon ){
        console.log("Found the Icon");
        category.cssString=icons[i].cssString;
    }
}
```

Easy, relatively fast, but seems a bit wasteful, so is there a smoother  way. Made a simple jfiddle if anyone wants to test.

https://jsfiddle.net/vrghost/9tw4btyo/1/

Answer (score 0):

If they are not ordered and you want to perform only one lookup. Then your algorithm is the best way to go. It takes o(n) to complete, taking 1 step in the best case (if it's the first icon) or n=icons.length in the worst.

If they are ordered by id, then you can try a binary search algorithm:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

If you want to perform several lookups on the icons array, then the best way to go is create an object with the id as property and the objects as values:

```
var iconObject = (function(icons) {
    var value = {};
    for (var i in icons){
        value[icons[i]._id] = icons[i];
    }        
    return value;
})(icons);

$scope.category.cssString = iconObject[$scope.category.categoryIcon].cssString;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/80g5gg3k/1/

Edit:

If you have the chance to change the API then return the data as an object directly instead of an array (if it doesn't kill your RESTful approach). This way you will not have to preprocess it. Return something like:

```
{
  "55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a68c": {
       "_id":"55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a68c",
       "iconName":"Sport",
       "cssString":"fa fa-futbol-o",
        "__v":0
    },
    "55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a69d":{
       "_id":"55dc79b2ed0fcf4a58d4a69d",
       "iconName":"Travel",
       "cssString":
       "fa fa-plane",
       "__v":0
    }
}
```

Sample fiddle for this last approach:
https://jsfiddle.net/5jvxusjw/1/

Comment: So as per your answer, the option is either spend a lot of time faffing about ordering your lists and rebuilding data before sending it from the API, or just live with the for loop. (As I read my answer I realised that it sounds a bit rude, that is not my intention, I greatly appreciate your answer, and I wanted the discussion going :) )

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect an alternative approach if you can change the API.